# Xamarin.forms webservice call using async task with progress dialog

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.ios

I'm new to developing a project using Xamarin.forms (Cross platform). I have been trying to find an example for calling web-service asynchronously with progress dialog so long for (droid and ios ).It should be compatible for both by writing the code on shared(master) instance. I couldn't get any solution to achieve things get done.Can anyone give me assistance on this? It would be great the solution along with the progress dialog.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please, show us what you already did.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to find any example to do. have no proper idea on it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should start with this nuget packet [Acr.XamForms.UserDialogs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Acr.XamForms.UserDialogs/)

There is also an example how to use progress dialog with async-await [here](https://github.com/aritchie/acr-xamarin-forms/blob/master/Samples/Samples/ViewModels/UserDialogViewModel.cs)

```
 public ICommand Progress {
        get {
            return new Command(async () => {
                var cancelled = false;

                using (var dlg = dialogService.Progress("Test Progress")) {
                    dlg.SetCancel(() => cancelled = true);
                    while (!cancelled && dlg.PercentComplete < 100) {
                        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
                        dlg.PercentComplete += 2;
                    }
                }
                this.Result = (cancelled ? "Progress Cancelled" : "Progress Complete");                    
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks. using Acr library is the proper way by apply in my existing PCL project ? Please advice.

Comment: yes, you can look at full sample at github https://github.com/aritchie/acr-xamarin-forms/tree/master/Samples

Comment: This has lot of dependencies.In samples itself throws exceptions.let me go thru it. Please direct me for any other samples. Thanks